Why does thread disorder occur when the FastAPI multithread return generator?
I want to implement a web service with streaming output using FastAPI. During the pressure test, it is found that for the same request, not the same thread is executed all the time. As a result, some intermediate variables stored in threadlocal are disordered. I have implemented a demo and pressure-tested it.  May I ask why doesn't the stream return the same thread for the same request?
import logging
import threading
import time

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sse_starlette import EventSourceResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def stream_output():
    logging.warning(f"{threading.current_thread().ident}")
    return EventSourceResponse(num_generator(10), headers={"thread": str(threading.current_thread().ident)})


def num_generator(n):
    for i in range(n):
        logging.warning(f"{threading.currentThread().ident}: %s" % i)
        time.sleep(2)
        yield f"thread: {threading.current_thread().ident} num: {i}"
    logging.warning(f"{threading.current_thread().ident}: end")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)

Pressure test result:

result of one of the requests:
data: thread: 39404 num: 0  
  
data: thread: 39404 num: 1  
  
data: thread: 57624 num: 2  
  
data: thread: 39404 num: 3  
  
data: thread: 52536 num: 4  
  
data: thread: 39404 num: 5  
  
data: thread: 52536 num: 6  
  
data: thread: 39404 num: 7  
  
data: thread: 39404 num: 8  
  
data: thread: 52536 num: 9

I expect same thread for the same request
data: thread: 56052 num: 0

data: thread: 56052 num: 1

data: thread: 56052 num: 2

data: thread: 56052 num: 3

data: thread: 56052 num: 4

data: thread: 56052 num: 5

data: thread: 56052 num: 6

data: thread: 56052 num: 7

data: thread: 56052 num: 8

data: thread: 56052 num: 9


"the stream does not return the same thread for the same request"  Why should it?  It would not make sense for the package to keep track of all the requests it receives, and check each request against this history in order to guarantee the behavior that you want.  I think you would be better off trying to implement your program without this expectation.

The answer you are looking for should be found, in part, in the source code of the third-party library you are using to send Server Sent Events (SSE); more specifically, in the implementation of the EventSourceResponse class, which you seem to be returning from the / endpoint.
Similarly to the official FastAPI/Starlette's StreamingResponse —please have a look at this answer and this answer for more details and explanation—the reason for the various threads appearing in the logs is that when you pass a synchronous generator to  EventSourceResponse (i.e., a normal def function instead of async def), such as the num_generator() funciton in your example, EventSourceResponse will execute the def function in a separate thread from an external threadpool and then await it, using Starlette's iterate_in_threadpool() (see the relevant implementation of EventSourceResponse).
Again, please take a look at the linked answers above for more details.

Thx for your comprehensive comment!
I have read those answers and try some times. But still got one question. When generator was processed to asyncgenerator in iterate_in_threadpool(), is one thread from threadpool execute one asyncgenerator or execute one singl step of asyncgenerator?
Is there any methods to achieve the result that I expected?

If you passed an async generator instead, it would run directly in the event loop, which runs in the main thread; hence, no threads from the threadpool would be used. In addition to the links provided above, you might find this answer helpful as well, with regard to the threadpool.

Thanks anyway, I tried other ways to solve the problem.
